# TikZ-UML: How to place stereotype next to relation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-uml

is there an easy way to position a stereotype next to a relation instead of "over" it? (or at least to add a white background to the stereotype?)

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \umlclass[type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}  
    \umlimpl[stereo=realizes, pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}

    \umlclass[x=4, type=interface]{InterfaceB}{}{}
    \umlclass[x=4, y=-4]{ClassB}{}{}  
    \umlimpl[]{ClassB}{InterfaceB}
    \node[] at (3,-2) {<<realizes>>}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading the documentation, the stereotype is always placed over the arrow.

Comment: Where is `tikz-uml` to be found? It doesn't seem to be standard?

Comment: You can find it here: [TikZ-UML website](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/).

It really is not standard, but it is the best way to draw UML diagrams with Latex that I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**REVISED APPROACH** with `xpatch`

See the original method below for the description of the logic...here, I just managed to incorporate it via `xpatch`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\umlrelation}{\stereotype}{\discardedstereotype}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\umlrelation}{\stereotype}{\discardedstereotype}{}{}
\def\stereotypel{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$%
   \noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\phantom{~$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$~}}%
\def\stereotyper{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\phantom{~$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType%
  $\gg$~}$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
\def\stereotypec{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
\def\stereotype{\if\relax\tikzumlRelationStereoType\relax\else%
  \csname stereotype\stereoalignment\endcsname\fi}%
\def\stereoalignment{c}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\def\stereoalignment{l}
    \umlclass[type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}
    \umlimpl[stereo=realizes, pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}

\def\stereoalignment{c}
    \umlclass[x=3, type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[x=3, y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}
    \umlimpl[stereo=realizes, pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}

\def\stereoalignment{r}
    \umlclass[x=6, type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[x=6, y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}
    \umlimpl[stereo=realizes, pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}

    \umlclass[x=9, type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[x=9, y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}
    \umlimpl[pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL APPROACH**

I edited my copy of  `tikz-uml.sty`, because I couldn't make it work via `\xpatchcmd`.  In the style under the macro `\umlrelation`, there is this block of code

```
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlRelationStereoType}{}}{%
    \def\stereotype{}%
  }{%
    \def\stereotype{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
  }%
```

which I changed to this:

```
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlRelationStereoType}{}}{%
    \def\stereotype{}%
  }{%
    \def\stereotypel{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\phantom{~$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$~}}%
    \def\stereotyper{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\phantom{~$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$~}$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
    \def\stereotypec{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
    \def\stereotype{\csname stereotype\stereoalignment\endcsname}%
    \@ifundefined{stereoalignment}{\def\stereoalignment{c}}{}%
  }%
```

in which, instead of `\stereotype` simply being defined, I define `\stereotypel`, `\stereotypec`, and `\stereotyper` to give the various alignments.  Then I redefine `\stereotype` to call upon one of these, depending on the value of the macro `\stereoalignment` as `l`, `c`, or `r`.  If it is not defined by the user, it defaults to `c`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}

% I CHANGED THE \stereotype DEFINITION IN \umlrelation FROM THIS:
%  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlRelationStereoType}{}}{%
%    \def\stereotype{}%
%  }{%
%    \def\stereotype{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
%  }%
% TO THIS:
%  \ifthenelse{\equal{\tikzumlRelationStereoType}{}}{%
%    \def\stereotype{}%
%  }{%
%    \def\stereotypel{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\phantom{~$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$~}}%
%    \def\stereotyper{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\phantom{~$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$~}$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
%    \def\stereotypec{$\ll$\tikzumlRelationStereoType$\gg$}%
%    \def\stereotype{\csname stereotype\stereoalignment\endcsname}%
%    \@ifundefined{stereoalignment}{\def\stereoalignment{c}}{}%
%  }%

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\def\stereoalignment{l}
    \umlclass[type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}
    \umlimpl[stereo=realizes, pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}

\def\stereoalignment{c}
    \umlclass[x=4, type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[x=4, y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}
    \umlimpl[stereo=realizes, pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}

\def\stereoalignment{r}
    \umlclass[x=8, type=interface]{InterfaceA}{}{}
    \umlclass[x=8, y=-4]{ClassA}{}{}
    \umlimpl[stereo=realizes, pos stereo=0.5]{ClassA}{InterfaceA}
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try that asap and accept the answer :)